# Setting the width and heights value in div's style tag from variables

Tags: javascript, html, styles, height, width

In my javascript file I have the following line:

```
<div id="mygraph" style="width:200px;height:100px;"></div>
```

I'd like to set the width and height values in the style tag from two variables that take their values from the corresponding functions:

```
var my_width = getWidth();
var my_height = getHeight();
```

How can I accomplish that? I'm missing the correct syntax. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following assumes that `my_height` and `my_width` returned by your functions are plain numbers:

```
document.getElementById('mygraph').style.height = my_height + "px";
document.getElementById('mygraph').style.width = my_width + "px";
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan. I included these two lines in the <script></script> and I removed the style tag from the div like this: <body><div id="mygraph"></div></body>. But, the graph does not appear! I feel I'm doing something fundamentally wrong :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you Zoltan! This is what I wanted to do. Problem solved!